# AutoFilter on multi values found on TextBox (ActiveX)

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, autofilter

I have a TextBox on my sheet to get its value to be used as a criteria on another AutoFilter code.
I have set `MutliLine` property of that textbox to be True.
If I copied one cell and paste on the textbox and pressed Enter, then the code runs correctly.
**But** If copied **multi cells** and paste on the textbox and pressed Enter, then the result of AutoFilter is nothing with no error raised.
I found the values are pasted already on textbox.
So, I need the Sub `Filter_WoNumber` accept all the values on textbox as a criteria.
In Advance, greatly thanks for your helps.
This is the code on sheet module:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = Asc(vbCr) Then                 'Run code after press EnterKey
       If Me.TextBox3.Value <> "" Then
            crit_Filter = TextBox3.Value        '"crit_Filter" is a public variable
            Filter_WoNumber
       End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

and this is the main sub used to AutoFilter:

```
Public crit_Filter As String

Sub Filter_WoNumber()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lcol_n As Long, lastcol As String, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

     lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                      'Last_Row on Column "A"
       lcol_n = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column          'Last_Column number on Row_2
        lastcol = Split(Cells(1, lcol_n).Address(True, False), "$")(0)      'Letter of Last_Column

    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:" & lastcol & lRow)                              'Source Range to apply Filter on it

    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter                            'Set AutoFilter if not already set
       ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
      
    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=crit_Filter, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Autofilter is very finicky about its filter criteria.. When multiple cells were copy/pasted in the textbox, what does your `crit_Filter` look like?

Comment: @Notus_Panda ,`crit_Filter` is a numeric values and I found that it has a right spaces ( I could not remove it even after using `Application.Trim(TextBox3.Value)`

Comment: I'm just asking because if you pass "2596 2520 2459" (random example) to the Autofilter, it would try to filter for the entire string, not the individual values since it isn't an array of your values, just a string (if I'm not misreading your code).

Comment: Try `Split(Trim(crit_Filter))`. `AutoFilter` 'likes' strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiLine` property **only allows to the text to pass on the next line**... Also to paste consecutive cells, separating their values by line end separator. You need to extract **an array** which to contain the separated strings to be used in the next (filtering) step.

So, try the next way:

1. Change the public variable declaration:

```
Public crit_Filter As Variant
```

2. Change the text box event code:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = Asc(vbCr) Then                              'Run code after press EnterKey
       If Me.TextBox3.Value <> "" Then
            crit_Filter = Split(TextBox3.Text, vbCrLf) '"crit_Filter" is a public (array) variable
            Filter_WoNumber
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work, I think...

**Edited**:

I tested the above code part and it works as I supposed, except the fact that after pasting a multi range in the text box an extra empty line is also inserted. So, the next function is able to trim it:

```
Function Filt(arr) As Variant
   Dim ar, ub As Long, i As Long, k As Long
   ar = arr: ub = UBound(ar)
   For i = UBound(arr) To 0 Step -1
       k = k + 1
       If arr(i) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve ar(ub - k + 1): Exit For
   Next i
   Filt = ar
End Function
```

And the splitting line in the event code should be changed in the  next way:

```
   crit_Filter = Filt(Split(TextBox3.Text, vbCrLf)) '"crit_Filter" is a public (array) variable
```

**Second Edit**:

To filter all empty cells in the copied range (from the text box), please use the next function:

```
Function filtEmpty(arr) As Variant 'filters all empty elements
   Dim ar, i As Long, k As Long
   ReDim ar(UBound(arr))

   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
       If arr(i) <> "" Then ar(k) = arr(i): k = k + 1
   Next i
   If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve ar(k - 1)
   
   filtEmpty = ar
End Function
```

Of course, instead of:

you should use:

```
     crit_Filter = filtEmpty(Split(TextBox3.Text, vbCrLf))
```

Comment: If I paste one cell contains one numeric value, then it works ok. But, If I paste consecutive cells e.g `("A3:A5"`) then autofilter is applied for `"A3"` only.

Comment: @Waleed It shouldn't, I think... Please, insert the next testing line, somewhere above the line doing the filtering: `Debug.print Join(crit_Filter, "|"):Stop`. What does it show in `Immediate Window` when stopped on this line? Isn't it a 1D Array elements (you want), separated by "|"? If not, I would like to understand the process of copying the range in the text box. Do you confirm that all cells are there, **on their own line**? I hope, there is no any blanc cell in the copied range...

Comment: Please accept my apology , I have tried on a different workbook  without setting the property of `MultiLine` to true. Now it works perfectly as supposed 

Comment: @Waleed Non need of a  new question... I will edit the code and place a function able to replace **All empty elements")...

Comment: I also found out that `AutoFilter` outputs only four (4) values , I tried many times but the same issue. I checked the textbox and it contains all the initial's values

Comment: @Waleed Please, use the new function, able to eliminate **all empty elements**. I also updated the first one, which did  not use the declared `k` variable... To eliminate empty elements (iterate backwards) up to the first non empty one. Anyhow, the recently added function is able to replace the first one completely. It will iterate between all array elements (not only the last ones), but this will take less than a second for some thousands elements...

Comment: I tried the Second Edit , It fixed (AutoFilter outputs only four values) and also eliminated the hidden cells  , But If I selected multiple cells using CTRL , then the in-between cells are also included

Comment: @Waleed This has nothing to do with the above code. It works as it should, **but that is the way Excel handles the discontinuous cells pasting in the text box**. Look to the text box after pasting. You will see all of them there...

Comment: @Waleed If you want/need to work with such discontinuous (selected) ranges, you should preliminarily paste them somewhere in a cell of an empty column, then copy the (selected) range and paste it in the text box.

Comment: Ok understood, I was confident that only you can answer my main question.

Comment: @Waleed Certainly, NOT only me... For instance, VBasic2008 rapidly understood that it is a matter of splitting the string to obtain an array. He, probably, missed that there are words **on different lines** and suggested splitting on the default character (" " - space). He placed a comment just before I pasted my answer code. I must confess my belief that the answer was much easier than it should. Probably, not too many VBA skilled people could see the question at that time...

Comment: Is that means that using vbasic2008 suggestion but with `vbCrLf` as a delimiter, is the same as your answer?

Comment: Yes, except the need of filtering the empty gaps.

Comment: @Waleed Some hours before I could see a comment asking about using strings with wildcards on the copied ranges **lines*. Now I am at home and I cannot see it... The answer would be: It can be done, but it would be but, probably, it will not be of much help. AFAIK, `AutoFilter` does not accept more than two criteria using wildcards. The same in arrays. It can be done in a different way, I think. This if you really need it, or try learning a possible way.